# How to "autoremove" packages with aptitude package manager?

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

Is it possible to perform an equivalent of `apt-get autoremove` with `aptitude`?  If yes, how?

The Debian Administrator's Handbook [says](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.apt-get.en.html#sect.automatic-tracking) that `aptitude` "autoremoves" packages automatically, but this is not true (not always true).  In my case (Ubuntu GNOME 16.04), I have a linux kernel which `apt-get autoremove` suggests to get me rid of:

```
§ sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for alexey: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 295 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

`aptitude`, however, does not care about it.

---

Here is the output of `aptitude why linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic`:

```
i   ubuntu-gnome-desktop         Depends    gdm3                                                      
i A gdm3                         Recommends xserver-xorg                                              
c   xserver-xorg                 Recommends xserver-xorg-video-all | xorg-driver-video                
p   virtualbox-guest-x11         Provides   xorg-driver-video                                         
p   virtualbox-guest-x11         Depends    virtualbox-guest-utils (= 5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2)   
p   virtualbox-guest-utils       Recommends virtualbox-guest-dkms (= 5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) | v
                                            irtualbox-guest-source (= 5.0.32-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) | 
                                            virtualbox-guest-modules                                  
i A linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic Provides   virtualbox-guest-modules
```

Here is the output of `aptitude search '~i linux.*4.4.0-31' -F '%c%a%M %p'`:

```
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-31
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic
i A linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
i A linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
```

Comment: What does `aptitude why linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic` output?

Comment: @StephenKitt, i have added the output of `aptitude why linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic`.

Answer (score 4):

Automatic packages that are no longer used are marked as "id" in aptitude.

I find three ways to remove them.

1. Aptitude UI

   `sudo aptitude`

   Press `g` to preview packages to be installed and removed.

   [image]

   You can find those packages under "Packages being removed because they are no longer used". Then press `g` again, aptitude will remove those packages.
2. Aptitude command line with grep and xargs

   `aptitude search ~i | grep ^id | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo aptitude purge -y`
3. Aptitude command line with `Aptitude::Delete-Unused` option

   `sudo aptitude -o Aptitude::Delete-Unused=1 install`

   > Option: Aptitude::Delete-Unused
   >
   > Default: true
   >
   > Description: If this
   >   option is true, automatically installed packages which are no longer
   >   required will be automatically removed. For more information, see the
   >   section called “Managing automatically installed packages”.

   I found this solution from http://www.lambdacurry.com/2013/12/aptitude-equivalent-of-apt-get-autoremove/. And the option is described in "Configuration file reference" in the aptitude reference manual. I don't have enough reputation to post more links, so you can search around for the document.

Either of them works for me.

According to [6.2.7. Tracking Automatically Installed Packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.apt-get.en.html#sect.automatic-tracking):

> With this information, when packages are removed, the package managers can compute a list of automatic packages that are no longer needed (because there is no “manually installed” packages depending on them).

and [Managing automatically installed packages](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s02s06.html):

> More precisely: they will be removed when there is no path via Depends, PreDepends, or Recommends to them from a manually installed package.

My answer applies only when there is no path of dependency (Depends, PreDepends, or Recommends) from a manually installed package to the target package. Thus there is no means of using `aptitude` to do the same thing as `apt-get autoremove` does in the situation described in the question (there exists a dependency path from `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`).

Comment: No, they are not marked for deletion.  By the way, normally, to remove packages marked for deletion and to perform other pending actions, it is enough to run `aptitude install`.

Comment: There is a clue in the footnote of [Managing automatically installed packages](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s02s06.html), "they(auto installed packages) will be removed when there is no path via Depends, PreDepends, or Recommends to them from a manually installed package." Maybe that's the situation that you have met. `aptitude why` traces up to a manually installed package "ubuntu-gnome-desktop". I don't know whether aptitude treats the dependency valid even if the path is broken in the middle, but it seems to be the case.

Comment: Well, my question is how to reproduce `apt-get autoremove` with `aptitude`, because the behaviour of `apt-get autoremove` in my case works well for me.

Comment: @Alexey, IMHO, aptitude doesn't seem to be able to do that in your situation because it still regards the dependency present. Hope someone would point out if I misunderstand that. I think I should add some limitations to my answer.

Comment: Apparently Aptitude::Delete-Unused is now default to true.